# InfiniBand RDMA: Do you need the RDMA Connection Manager?

Tags: connection, infiniband

When doing RDMA transfers over InfiniBand, is the RDMA Connection Manager required? (Also, are all calls with the prefix `rdma_` related to the RDMA Connection Manager?)

Also, there are no appropriate tags for this since I cannot create `rdma` or `infiniband`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDMA connection manager isn't mandatory for InfiniBand. It is possible to exchange parameters for an InfiniBand connection over a side-channel (e.g. over a TCP connection on top of IPoIB). For an example you can look at the `ibv_rc_pingpong` program that is part of the `libibverbs` library.

However, RDMA connection manager hides some of the complexity of setting up a connection, such as requesting the path information from the subnet manager.

The calls with the `rdma_` prefix are part of `librdmacm`. Most of them are for using the connection manager to set up connections, but some are just wrappers or helper functions for the communication itself.